# How to suppress error message from shell that is invoked by a C++ binary file?

Tags: shell, error-handling, binary

I have a shell script `A.sh`, it calls a file `B.o` to run such as the following

```
#A.sh
B &
```

So the ampersand states, I am running the process B at the background. However, if `B` produced an error message, I do not want to see it. I tried to redirect the error message when running `A.sh` such as

```
./A 2>&1
```

but the error messages produced by `B` still comes up. Is there a way to suppress the error messages that result from a subprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
2>&1
```

Redirect standard error to standard out.
So you will see all the output from A (and B).

What you probably want is:

```
B 2> /dev/null &
```

This runs B in the background and redirects standard output to `/dev/null` (this is a sink and it disapears). All normal messages from B are still forward. But you can redirect both output streams.

```
B 2> /dev/null > /dev/null &
```

This runs B in the background and redirects all output to `/dev/null`.